# Tomcat 8.5 configuration with APR connecter and HTTPS

Tags: openssl, tomcat7, apr, tomcat8.5

For security reasons we should upgrade our application server from **Tomcat7** into **Tomcat8.5**(Tomcat is used as the application server in front of Apache HTTPD 2.4 which is the web server, they are integrated using [AJP with mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/)), after a successful configuration the application was able to run successfully but I noticed a high usage of CPU which reaches up to 100%.

Note that I used **Tomcat8.5.47 native** binaries for windows downloaded from [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi).

here is the config with which I enabled https in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8444" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
             maxThreads="150"
             enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
             acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
             SSLEnabled="true"
             SSLCertificateFile="conf/certs/mycacert.pem"
             SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/certs/cakey_enc.pem" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8444" />
```

Here is some details about the [AJP connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html#Standard_Implementations), refer specialy to the `protocol` attribute.

[image]

After a long comparion between Tomcat7 and Tomcat8.5, When I entred https://localhost:port/manager/status for both Tomcat 7 and 8.5, I found that Tomcat7 is using `http-apr-8080`(for http), `http-apr-8443`(for https, it's mentioned http-apr and not https-apr) and `ajp-apr-8009`, but Tomact8.5 uses `http-nio-8080`, `https-openssl-nio-8444` and `ajp-nio-8009`

So Tomcat7 uses [APR](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/apr.html#APR_Connectors_Configuration) in all connectors but Tomcat8.5 uses NIO.

Additionnel informations:

We are running Windows Server 2008 R2 64bits, with 4GB RAM(this is a test server).

APR 1.7

AJP 1.3

JVM 1.8.0_231-b11

Tomcat Initial memory pool: 1024MB

Tomcat Maximum memory pool: 1024MB

Openssl 1.1.1c

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you consider using [mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) for connecting Apache with Tomcat?

Comment: @f_puras No I didn't as the old configuration uses mod_jk and works fine, would this change something with Tomcat8.5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread [High CPU load with the JSSE client poller on Tomcat 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895884/high-cpu-load-with-the-jsse-client-poller-on-tomcat-8-5) gave me the idea to try `Tomcat8.5.5`, it solves the problem with the spontaneous High CPU Usage when using `Apr Connector`

Answer (score 3):

The defaults have changed in 8.5.x when the APR/native library is present.

In Tomcat 7 it was APR connector including OpenSSL for TLS.

In Tomcat 8.5 it is NIO connector including OpenSSL for TLS.

Using OpenSSL requires the APR/native connector.

If you really want APR/native (personally I'd stick with the defaults) the simplest way of doing it is to use the following in your HTTP `Connector` element 
`protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"` and `protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol"` for your AJP connector.

Comment: The information about the default connector in Tomcat 7 and 8.5 is useful, but this doesn't explain why I'm getting high CPU usage specially when I set Tomcat to use APR/native connector, I'm trying to collect threads dumps to see what's wrong.

Could you give me link that says this "In Tomcat 8.5 it is NIO connector including OpenSSL for TLS." ?

This discussion here http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Can-t-Get-SSL-to-Work-in-8-5-td5071245.html is pretty the same as my situation but it doesn't provide the solution for that.